# Adding new version of PHP to MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm using MAMP PRO 4.5, bought it couple of years ago. Only issue is that they stopped supplying new versions of PHP, latest is 7.2.1.

Is there a way to update to a newer version manually?

Comment: I suggest you to wait. (they need time to port to MAMP).

Comment: Probably gonna take waiting a couple of years then... I'm curious if there isn't a way to do this yourself by compiling ?

Comment: According to https://www.mamp.info/de/versionshistorie/windows/, the latest version of MAMP Pro (4.2.0, released in June 2020) contains PHP 7.4 - so what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are sticking with MAMP  then you'll just have to wait. I have MAMP PRO too, but I only use it for one ancient project now.

If you don't mind ditching MAMP, can I suggest that you might like to try Docker! I'm on a Mac and it gives you a consistent Linux box across machines etc. On my Mac the only tools I use are Docker, VirtualBox, Git, PHPStorm, and Sequel Pro. There isn't any PHP or LAMP stack stuff!

https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v19.03.1

https://www.virtualbox.org/

To get started, you create your Virtual machine via Docker, you only need to do this once:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

To start it up, type the following

```
docker-machine start
```

You now have a working Docker Machine. Now that it's started, you need to run this for every tab you open in the terminal
in order to set up its environment variables in your terminal.

```
eval $(docker-machine env)
```

You can now start working with your various docker projects.

I have a fully configured and ready to roll LAMP stack here https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp

It uses PHP 8 FPM, but you can change a setting in `build/php/Dockerfile`, for instance for PHP 7.4 you can use `delboy1978uk/php74:1.1.5`

Git clone that into a project folder, cd in, and type

```
docker-compose up
```

You'll see it initialise (the first time is always a wee bit longer), then you'll be left with live scrolling LAMP stack log output.

Now open another tab, and again run `eval $(docker-machine env)`. To get inside your Linux box (for instance to run Composer) type:

```
docker-composer exec php /bin/bash
```

Your Apache isn't localhost anymore, its the IP of the virtalbox machine. Type `docker-machine env` and copy the IP address into your `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.99.100 awesome.scot
```

`awesome.scot` can also be configured to whatever you like in the `docker-compose.yml` but you will also need to tweak `build/httpd/Dockerfile` on the line that generates the self signed cerificate.

You should now be able to browse to `https://awesome.scot` and see a holding page, you now have Apasche + SSL, PHP, MariaDb, and MailHog (goto `https://awesome.scot:8025` to view, port 1025 to send).

When done devving, `CTRL-C` out. and then type

```
docker-compose down
```

which will tidy things up.

Comment: Why VirtualBox and not just Docker? (seriously interested)

Comment: Actually, I've pretty much ditched all VirtualBox stuff now we don't need to use `docker-machine`, check the `README.md` on my repo for updated instructions :-D Have a great day!